# loop through the lines which are specified through a parameter

Tags: java, loops, kotlin, filereader, file-processing

I have a chunk of code below which reads from a file in s3 and processes all the lines. The file doesn't have any line numbers in it. However, I want the code to process only specific lines of file. How should I approach that?
Note: The start line number and end line number are being passed as parameter.
Below is the current code

````
var counter=0
s3Service.getS3FileBufferedReader(s3File).use { s3BufferedReader ->

            s3BufferedReader.useLines { lines ->

                lines.forEach {
                    // Process each line


                    val transaction = Transaction(it)

                    // does some processing 

                    counter ++
                    log.info("Line number: ${counter}")
                }
            }
        }```

What I'm trying to achieve is, instead of processing the whole file, I want to process lines from 10 to 20. The catch is, the file only has data and no line numbers in it.
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `Sequence#drop(Int)` and `Sequence#take(Int)` for this:

```kotlin
lines.drop(start - 1).take(end - start + 1).forEach {
    // do your stuff with the line
}
```